# Matlab script execution from bash

Tags: bash, matlab

I am able to execute the following from terminal :

```
matlab -nojvm < span.m
```

This works fine and produces the required output.

However, in the same directory, if I write a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash


matlab -nojvm < span.m
```

I get the following error when I execute it:

```
wallShearStresswallsconstant=importdata("wallShearStress_wallBottom.raw");
                                         |
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
 Undefined function 'wallShearStresswallsconstant' for input arguments of type
'double'.
```

Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly.

The matlab script is as follows and it reads a file (wallShearStress_wallBottom.raw) with 6 columns and 45288 rows (all numbers), for testing purpose dosent matter what numbers are there.

```
clear all 
clc
wallShearStresswallsconstant=importdata("wallShearStress_wallBottom.raw");
ly=110;%64; %nz
lx=407;%239;%nx
ShearStress=zeros(lx,5);
%Uinf=15.894579;
Uinf=16.77;
i=1;
j=1;
k=1;

while i<lx+1
    while j<ly+1
        ShearStress(i,1)=wallShearStresswallsconstant(k,1);
        ShearStress(i,2)=wallShearStresswallsconstant(k,2);
        ShearStress(i,3)=wallShearStresswallsconstant(k,3);
        if wallShearStresswallsconstant(k,4) < 0
            ShearStress(i,4)=ShearStress(i,4)+1;
        else
            ShearStress(i,5)=ShearStress(i,5)-1;
        end
        j=j+1;
        k=k+1;
    end
    j=1;
    i=i+1;
end

SS = ShearStress;
SS(:,5) = SS(:,4)-SS(:,5);
SS(:,4) = SS(:,4)./SS(:,5);
plot(SS(:,1),SS(:,4))
SS = SS';

fileID = fopen('new.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f\n',SS);
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: i just added the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following code instead:

```
importdata('wallShearStress_wallBottom.raw');
```

And the common bash command for executing matlab script file is like this:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r \
    "try, span, catch, exit(1), end, exit(0);"
```

where `span` is your `.m` filename.

Comment: that didnt solve the problem. I have added the matlab script if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: @adder why use double quotation marks? Should it be `importdata('wallShearStress_wallBottom.raw');`?

Comment: its just a habit, and matlab works with both but that solved the problem with executing matlab from the script. I am not sure why the bash script would care when matlab dosent. Thank you!

Comment: @adder ok, I've put it in the answer. Please accept my answer if it helps. Thanks.